# Symfony 2 optional route url parts (wildcard?)

Tags: php, symfony, routes, wildcard

In Symfony 2.2.1 Is it possible to create route like:

```
/search/category_ids/1,2,3,4/subcategory_ids/32,23,9/language_ids/10,23,5 ...
```

where every url part is optional, for example user could visit url

```
/search/category_ids/1,2,3,4/language_ids/10,23,5 ...
```

or even

```
/search/subcategory_ids/2,23
```

I would like to get away from traditional get parameters in favor of this, mainly for aesthetic appeal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While some frameworks discourage the use of query strings, symfony doesn't, and you should just pass the parameters in a query string:

```
/search?category_ids=1,2,3,4&subcategory_ids=...
```

These parameters can be accessed through the request object:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request) {
    $category_ids = $request->query->get('category_ids');
}
```

If you really really need to pass the parameters in the path, you can achieve the same result with a "match all" parameter at the end of your route:

```
@Route("/search/{params}", requirements={"params"=".*"}, defaults={"params"=""})
public function searchAction($params) {

}
```

You can just parse `$params` like this:

```
$parts = explode('/', $params);
$map = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i+=2) {
    $map[$parts[$i]] = $parts[$i+1];
}
```

Comment: The solution solves the problem. 
But you lose the flexibility of the routing system, and now your controller has a new responsibility.

Comment: Note that route parameter names ({params} here) must be in lowercase.